# Linkedin API: Exchange JSAPI Token for REST API OAuth Token

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm having some difficulty exchanging my JSAPI token for a REST API token.  I'm using this for reference:

https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens

I've: set up a self signed SSL cert locally, so Linkedin's secure cookie works properly; given my app r_basicprofile and r_emailaddress permissions.

Here's my front end code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: **MY_CLIENT_ID**
    authorize: true
    credentials_cookie: true
</script>

...

$('.linkedin-signin').click(function(e) {       
    IN.User.authorize( function () {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(function(data) {
            $.post(location.origin+'/api/account/create/linkedin', { 'lId': data.id } ).done(function(result) {                 
                console.log(result);    
            });
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

And here is my PHP code, which is almost exactly as in their docs:

```
$consumer_key = '**MY_CLIENT_ID**';
$consumer_secret = '**MY_CLIENT_SECRET**';
$cookie_name = "linkedin_oauth_${consumer_key}";
$credentials_json = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]; 
$credentials = json_decode($credentials_json);

$access_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken';               

$oauth = new OAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
$access_token = $credentials->access_token;

// swap 2.0 token for 1.0a token and secret
$oauth->fetch($access_token_url, array('xoauth_oauth2_access_token' => $access_token), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);
```

Everything looks good, but on `$oauth->fetch`, I get the error:

```
OAuthException(code: 401): Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
```

Which leads me to believe that the token is invalid... but it's taken directly from the cookie, so how could it be invalid?  Any ideas?

Comment: have you had any luck finding a solution for that issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I'm a little annoyed that Linkedin directs people here for tech support, but doesn't answer most of the questions.  I gave up and left Linkedin out of the social login options for my site.

Comment: I encountered the same issue, and this https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens is broken, I think maybe LinkedIn just removed this API

Comment: Hah, look at that. It's funny that they direct people to StackOverflow for support but don't respond to issues here.

Comment: Did anyone get anywhere with this? This is very frustrating

Comment: @Owen I gave up and dropped support for Linkedin sign-ins.

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator starting to go that way myself unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Today we got the weird 401 error too, apperently linkedin was broken, because after an hour it worked again without any changes on our side.

I found this site though and eventhough it's a really old post, i tought i'd share how we fixed it, which works.

JS Front-end

```
var AppConfig = {
    linkedin : {
        onLoad : "linkedinLibInit",
        api_key : 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        authorize : false,
        credentials_cookie: true
    }
};

window.linkedinLibInit = function ( response ) {
    // post init magic

    // cleanup window callback function
    delete window.linkedinLibInit;
}

$.getScript( "//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true", function success() {
    IN.init( AppConfig.linkedin );
} );


function connectToLinkedIn() {
    if ( IN.User.isAuthorized() ) {
        _linkedinAuthorized();
    }
    else {
        IN.User.authorize( _linkedinAuthorized );
    }
}

function _linkedinAuthorized() {
    IN.API.Profile( "me" )
        .fields( 'id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'location', 'industry', 'headline', 'picture-urls::(original)', 'email-address' )
        .result( function ( response ) {
            var accessToken = JSON.parse( $.cookie( 'linkedin_oauth_' + AppConfig.linkedin.api_key ) );
            // performApi Call to backend
        } )
        .error( function ( err ) {
            // render error
        } );
}
```

PHP Backend using PECL oAuth

```
function offlineAuthLinkedIn($accessToken, $linkedinConfig) {
    $oAuth = new \OAuth( $linkedinConfig['app_id'], $linkedinConfig['app_secret'] );
    $oAuth->fetch(
        'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken',
        array('xoauth_oauth2_access_token' => $accessToken),
        OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST
    );
    $response = null;
    parse_str($oAuth->getLastResponse(), $response);

    $oAuth->setToken($response['oauth_token'], $response['oauth_token_secret']);
    $oAuth->fetch(
        'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,headline,location,picture-url,picture-urls::(original),public-profile-url)',
        array(),
        OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET,
        array('x-li-format' => 'json')
    );
    $profile = json_decode($oAuth->getLastResponse(), true);
    $profile['user_id'] = $profile['id'];
    if (true == isset($profile['pictureUrl']))
    {
        $profile['profile_image'] = $profile['pictureUrl'];
        unset($profile['pictureUrl']);
    }
    return $profile;
}
```